# Codeigniter HMVC ERROR: This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I am using CodeIgniter and when I upload the project on the live server (with different config and database files), I get the following error:

> This webpage has a redirect loop.

**I have also checked the `.htaccess` file and removed all the hooks.**

Routes:

```
$route['default_controller']        =   "welcome";
$route['404_override']              =   'welcome/error';
```

Controller:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->content = array('vars' => array());
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('common/header', $this->content);
        $this->load->view('pages/home', $this->content);
        $this->load->view('common/footer', $this->content);
    }}
```

Comment: is your welcome controller in application > modules > modulename > controllers > Welcome.php if so then `$route['default_controller'] =   "welcome";` should be some thing like `$route['default_controller'] =   "modulename/welome/index";`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I think that was a bug in CI 2.2, not supported behavior. The default_controller should only be a controller or a controller/method pair. CI automatically checks the requested directory for the controller and, if not found, traverses the parent folders.

Comment: @ToniW the hmvc from here https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc use to be for codeigniter 2 versions but now only for codeigniter 3

Comment: Oh, nevermind, sorry! I didn't realize that was a thing.